# MySql query using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how can I write this query using Codeigniter.

```
SELECT ubani, COUNT(*) FROM   spots GROUP BY ubani
```

I tried below code but it doesn't worked

```
$this->db->query("SELECT 'ubani',COUNT(*) FROM 'spots' GROUP BY 'ubani'");
```

thank you...

Comment: I want to get something like this,what is on this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm

Comment: use back ticks ``` not `'`ticks for column/table names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use back ticks not ticks/apostrophe `'` for column/table names...

```
$this->db->query("SELECT `ubani`,COUNT(*) FROM `spots` GROUP BY `ubani`");
```

better yet, don't use them at all unless you have a reserved word or space...

```
$this->db->query("SELECT ubani,COUNT(*) FROM spots GROUP BY ubani");
```

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't worked because I had another  mistake :D, thank you! :)

Comment: can you help once more?

Comment: where and how can I use ORDER BY DESC query in this example,thank you

    SELECT ubani,COUNT(*) FROM spots GROUP BY ubani

Comment: `$this->db->query("SELECT ubani,COUNT(*) FROM spots GROUP BY ubani ORDER BY count(*) desc");`